# Por qué devuelve -1 al hacer rowcount en una consulta en SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

Intento ejecutar la siguiente busqueda desde una ventana de archivo:

```
     def verdatos(self):
         self.xdata = self.contar.CuentaTipoProceso1()
         self.lbldata = Label(self.frame30, text=self.xdata) 
         self.lbldata.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

a esta otra con la secuencia sql que quiero realizar:

```
def CuentaTipoProceso1(self):
    cur=self.cnn.cursor()
    sql='''SELECT count (*) FROM Usuarios WHERE Idioma = 'Español' '''
    cur.execute(sql)
    n=cur.rowcount
    self.cnn.commit()
    cur.close()
    return n
```

Resulta que no me sale ningún error, y al correr me da un resultado, pero no el esperado, se supone que la cuenta total es de `27`, pero me arroja un `-1`. He intentado cambiar la secuensia sql, cambiar las columnas y nombres de las variables que requiero de la base de datos, pero nada me funciona. Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El problema sucede porque al API de SQLite no puede determinar la cantidad de filas retornadas por la ejecución de la consulta.

Ver [La Documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount)

> As required by the Python DB API Spec, the rowcount attribute “is -1
> in case no executeXX() has been performed on the cursor or the
> rowcount of the last operation is not determinable by the interface”.
> This includes SELECT statements because we cannot determine the number
> of rows a query produced until all rows were fetched.

Por otro lado, la lógica también está mal, porque `count(*)` SIEMPRE va a devolver un único numero entero, que será la cantidad de registros que cumplen la condición, (0 o más coincidencias).

La solución al problema será simplemente hacer un `fetch` al resultado de la consulta y ya tendrás la cantidad de registros:

```py
sql='''SELECT count (*) FROM Usuarios WHERE Idioma = 'Español' '''
cur.execute(sql)
n = cur.fetchone()[0]
```